# Get Last month and Current month Data from Two table based on Response Text

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get `QuestionText` for all the question those were marked `yes` In last month but no in current month.

I have two table **QuestionMaster**

```
QuestionID | QuestionText
```

Other Table is **ResponsesMaster**

```
ResponseID | ResponseText | QuestionID | ResponseDateTime
```

Response Date Time is in `VARCHAR`.

Following Query Returns All the responses. I want as mentioned above.

```
SELECT QM.QuestionText, AR.AssessmentID, AR.ResponseText 
FROM QuestionMaster QM, ResponsesMaster AR 
WHERE AR.QuestionID = QM.QuestionID
```

Comment: How are you maintaining which questions were marked yes and no. Which column has that info ?

Comment: @rkumar ResponseText has value yes or no

Answer (score 1):

SELECT QM.QuestionText, AR.AssessmentID, AR.ResponseText 
FROM QuestionMaster QM, ResponsesMaster AR 
WHERE AR.QuestionID = QM.QuestionID and **Month(AR.ResponseDateTime)=MONTH(CURDATE()) and QR.QuestionText='Yes' and 
QR.QuestionID in (SELECT QM.QuestionID 
FROM QuestionMaster QM, ResponsesMaster AR 
WHERE AR.QuestionID = QM.QuestionID and Month(AR.ResponseDateTime)=MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) and QR.QuestionText='No')**

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Let me know how it works.

```
select qm.QuestionID,qm.QuestionText
from QuestionMaster qm
inner join ResponsesMaster rm on qm.QuestionID = rm.QuestionID and rm.ResponseText = 'N' and month(rm.ResponseDateTime) = month(curdate)
inner join ResponsesMaster rm1 on rm.QuestionID = rm1.QuestionID and rm1.ResponseText = 'Y' and month(rm1.ResponseDateTime) = month(last_day(curdate()) - interval 1 month);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, with MySQL @ variables, they work like inline programming.  I am starting by building whatever the first day of the current month is ex: yyyy-mm-01.  Then, go back one month for the Prior first of the month, and forward for first of next month.  If you just use the current date such as NOW 2016-06-06 @ 8:52am, then your last month is from May 06 @ 8:52am, but I think you really mean the calendar month vs literal month.

Now, I can use these variables for range criteria of >= FirstOfLastMonth AND < FirstOfThisMonth would account for all date/times up to 11:59:59pm of the last day of the month prior to first day of THIS month.  Likewise, going forward, up to 11:59:59pm of last day this month.  Such as if you wanted to compare historical data and wanted to force first of month something like '2016-02-01'

Now to get your data.  Start FIRST with those records explicitly marked as 'Yes' that you are looking for You are looking for the question text.  What if entered multiple times, such as different people taking a test and you have multiple entries.  I am just getting DISTINCT question IDs and their corresponding text.  No sense in asking for the response since you are explicitly looking for those now = 'no' where they started as 'yes'

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      QM.QuestionID,
      QM.QuestionText
   from
      ( select @FirstOfThisMonth := CONCAT( year(curdate()), '-', month( curdate()), '-01' ),
               @FirstOfLastMonth := date_add( @FirstOfThisMonth, interval -1 month ),
               @FirstOfNextMonth := date_add( @FirstOfThisMonth, interval +1 month ) ) sqlvars,
      ResponsesMaster RM
         JOIN QuestionMaster QM
            ON RM.QuestionID = QM.QuestionID

         JOIN ResponsesMaster RMNow
            ON RM.QuestionID = RMNow.QuestionID
            AND RMNow.ResponseText = 'no'
            AND RMNow.ResponseDateTime >= @FirstOfThisMonth
            AND RMNow.ResponseDateTime < @FirstOfNextMonth
   where
          RM.ResponseText = 'yes'
      AND RM.ResponseDateTime >= @FirstOfLastMonth
      AND RM.ResponseDateTime < @FirstOfThisMonth
```